# Git remote has diverged after renaming old commits

Tags: git

I made an error in my Git config (typo in my email) and had committed locally as well as pushed to the remote branch.

I ran a command to edit all my old commits to use the correct email.

Now I wish to push my changes to the remote server. As expected, currently I am getting the message `Your branch and 'origin/develop' have diverged`.

What should I do now? The only change between local and remote is that all the commits have an updated email attribute locally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Push force it. `git push -f origin master`. adjust name of the repo and your branch. That error is to be expected given that you rewrote the whole branch history.

Comment: this will replace the history of the branch on the remote with the history of the branch as you have it locally.